# parsing xml file with simplexml in php

Tags: php, simplexml

The following xml is a shortened sample xml returned from a web service for which I do not control. Can someone tell me how to use simplexml to first read the number of records in stats, and then properly iterate the equipment items so I can display the item price and quantity? Thanks.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <response>
     <inventory>
      <warehouse>
       <stats> 
        <location>Main</location>
        <reportTime>3/9/2013 16:50 PM</reportTime>
        <records>2</records>
       </stats>
       <equipment>
        <item>
         <model>B14</model>
         <status>Active</status>
         <price>410.33</price>
         <color>blue</color>
         <qty>100</qty>
        </item>
       </equipment>
       <equipment>
        <item>
         <model>C15</model>
         <status>Active</status>
         <price>199.10</price>
         <color>red</color>
         <qty>200</qty>
        </item>
       </equipment>
      </warehouse>
     </inventory>
    </response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = ...; // Your XML

$sx = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$numRecords = $sx->inventory->warehouse->stats->records;

foreach($sx->inventory->warehouse->equipment as $item) {
    echo $item->item->price,', ',$item->item->qty,'<br />';
}
?>
```

Outputs:

> 410.33, 100
>
> 199.10, 200